# Automatically generate nullable and not-null types in overriden methods

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, nullable, notnull

I'm trying to extend a `CameraCaptureSession.StateCallback`. So I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to select methods to be overriden. Android Studio 3.3 sees methods' parameters like platform types: `session: CameraCaptureSession!`.

However if I open the sources (SDK 27), I see `@android.annotation.NonNull CameraCaptureSession session`, where `NonNull` is marked by red "Cannot resolve symbol".

I've already added annotations `android.annotation.NonNull` and `android.annotation.Nullable` to Android Studio settings under "@NotNull/@Nullable problems". After that I've invalidated caches and restarted.

Code generation works the same way: parameters are nullable (`session: CameraCaptureSession?`).

I expect code generation make not nullable parameters in such cases (`session: CameraCaptureSession`).

My workaround now is to check sources of every overridden method and remove `?` marks if `@NotNull` is presented, but it's extremely monotonous.

So are there any ideas how to fix code generation?